# Weekly rankings repeated on SE weekly user leagues

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

The weekly rankings are being repeated on SE weekly user leagues, mainly on smaller sites.

For example [Bryan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/24/bryant)t is 1-8 on [Role-playing Games](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/48/week/rpg), and [Martín Marconcini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115/martin-marconcini) is 1-8 on [Apple](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/46/week/apple).  The same thing seems to be happening monthly, and only on the smaller sites.

<sub>Thanks to [ExTSR](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/72/extsr) for reporting this one.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed, and I think I found what caused it so hopefully it won't come back.